# How read a file into a seq of lines in F#

Tags: f#

This is C# version:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> ReadLinesEnumerable(string path) {
  using ( var reader = new StreamReader(path) ) {
    var line = reader.ReadLine();
    while ( line != null ) {
      yield return line;
      line = reader.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

But directly translating needs a mutable variable.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
open System.IO

let readLines (filePath:string) = seq {
    use sr = new StreamReader (filePath)
    while not sr.EndOfStream do
        yield sr.ReadLine ()
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Btw, is there a library function for that?

Comment: @David - There certainly should be. I believe the .NET libraries are slowly moving towards more IEnumerable interfaces.

Comment: I needed to read a file already opened by another process so I modified as: `use fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite); use sr = new StreamReader(fs)`

Comment: probably obvious to most but also needs an `open System.IO` directive

Answer (score 104):

If you're using .NET 4.0, you can just use [File.ReadLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383503(VS.100).aspx).

```
> let readLines filePath = System.IO.File.ReadLines(filePath);;

val readLines : string -> seq<string>
```

Comment: Does that require holding the entire file in memory at once, or can it process line by line?

Comment: "The ReadLines and ReadAllLines methods differ as follows: When you use ReadLines, you can start enumerating the collection of strings before the whole collection is returned; when you use ReadAllLines, you must wait for the whole array of strings be returned before you can access the array. Therefore, when you are working with very large files, ReadLines can be more efficient."

Answer (score 21):

To answer the question whether there is a library function for encapsulating this pattern - there isn't a function *exactly* for this, but there is a function that allows you to generate sequence from some state called `Seq.unfold`. You can use it to implement the functionality above like this:

```
new StreamReader(filePath) |> Seq.unfold (fun sr -> 
  match sr.ReadLine() with
  | null -> sr.Dispose(); None 
  | str -> Some(str, sr))
```

The `sr` value represents the stream reader and is passed as the state. As long as it gives you non-null values, you can return `Some` containing an element to generate and the state (which could change if you wanted). When it reads `null`, we dispose it and return `None` to end the sequence. This isn't a direct equivalent, because it doesn't properly dispose `StreamReader` when an exception is thrown.

In this case, I would definitely use sequence expression (which is more elegant and more readable in most of the cases), but it's useful to know that it could be also written using a higher-order function.

Comment: on using this i am getting the following exception: {"Cannot read from a closed TextReader."} at the `match sr.ReadLine() with` line. any help please as to why?

Comment: @AruniRC I think the solution by @ChaosPandion is much nicer than the one using `unfold`, so I would go with that :-)

Comment: @AruniRC, the Seq is lazy--by the time you evaluate it later in the code, the reader might already be closed, hence the `Cannot read from a closed TextReader`. You will have to force evaluation of the sequence immediately, for example by converting to list with `Seq.toList`, or some other trick.

Answer (score 15):

```
    let lines = File.ReadLines(path)                

    // To check
    lines |> Seq.iter(fun x -> printfn  "%s" x)
```

Answer (score 5):

On .NET 2/3 you can do:

```
let readLines filePath = File.ReadAllLines(filePath) |> Seq.cast<string>
```

and on .NET 4:

```
let readLines filePath = File.ReadLines(filePath);;
```

Comment: The first one of these is not lazy (`ReadAllLines` eagerly reads all lines into an array).

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid the "System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot read from a closed TextReader." exception, use:

```
let lines = seq { yield! System.IO.File.ReadLines "/path/to/file.txt" }
```