# How to read/write one line at a time from a text file in C#

Tags: file, file-io, f#

I want to read from the file "hello.txt" on line each time and then write this line to "bye.text" and to the screen.
How can I do this?
The only funcs I see in "File" are:

- readAllText
- readAllLines
- WriteAllLines, etc.

Comment: -1: Homework or not, you have to demonstrate some own effort to solve the problem. Don't ask people write it for you from scratch.

Comment: I did try!
I looked in the internet to find some funcs to help me read only one line and i didnt find!
I just need someone to tell me if there is a func in F# reading one line in the text
Ill do the rest.
Im sorry if it looked like I am trying to go the easy way.that is not true!

Comment: First google result for `f# read line from file` is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365527/how-read-a-file-into-a-seq-of-lines-in-f which appears to have the answer

Comment: @nati There are not called `functions` in these fully Object-Oriented langauges. They are called `methods` instead.

Comment: When I run into problems like this, where I don't know how to do it in F#, I look at how to first do it in C#, so I can get familiar with the .NET class names. Then I just apply F# syntax to get the job done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Jack says, you need to use the `StreamWriter` and `StreamReader` types if you want to work with files (or any other streams) using line-by-line functions. Just use the constructor like this:

```
open System.IO

let addLine (line:string) =     
  use wr = StreamWriter("D:\\temp\\test.txt", true)
  wr.WriteLine(line)
```

Here, we're using an overload of the `StreamWriter` constructor that takes the path (as a string) and boolean specifying that we want to append to an existing file. Also note that I'm using `use` keyword to make sure that the file is closed when `addLine` completes.

To read content as a sequence of lines, you can use `StreamReader` similarly - create an instance of the type using constructor and then use `ReadLine` method until you get `null` as a result.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `use wr = _new_ StreamWriter(...)` to have `Dispose` called when the scope ends? Why/why not?

Answer (score 3):

The methods in the `System.IO.File` class only support reading/writing the entire file. If you want a more granular approach (e.g., reading/writing line-by-line) you need to use something like `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`.

Comment: thanks!
but there is something I cant understand:
when I wrote:
 --  let newFile =File.Create("D:\FSharpTesting\Hello.out")
 --  File.AppendAllText(NewFile,str)
(str is the string I want to add).
then it said that the NewFile is a streamWriter and I need to write a string as the Path. 
so the only way I succeeded to do it is by writing the entire path every time: 
  -- File.AppendAllText("D:\FSharpTesting\Hello.out",str)
is there is a way to convert to stream to a string?