# F# Assigning a text file to a variable (string)

Tags: f#

In F# how do you assign the entire contents of a file (text file where it's 100% string type) to a variable?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Comment: Same as C#/VB.Net: `System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path)`

Comment: or [ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=fsharp#code-snippet-1).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How read a file into a seq of lines in F#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365527/how-read-a-file-into-a-seq-of-lines-in-f)

Comment: `let content = File.ReadAllText(path)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'd just a let binding, and the same `System.IO` functions that are normally available:

```
let theVariable = System.IO.File.ReadAllText pathToFile
```