# fsharp BinaryReader how to read till the end of a file?

Tags: .net, f#

I want to experiment with basic encryption and compression of files so my first question is if the ByteReader is the correct reader for the job? And my second most important question is: How do you loop til the end of a file when using a binary reader? is there a way to do it like a StreamReader as explained in [How read a file into a seq of lines in F#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2365527/how-read-a-file-into-a-seq-of-lines-in-f)?

I would like to do the following:

```
let reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open("anyFile",FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read)
let mutable data = []
while -condition i can't find- do
   data <- [reader.readBytes()] :: data
//do fancy things with the achieved data
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to read all the data from the stream to memory then the method [Stream.CopyTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx) could be the most simple solution:

```
use stream = File.Open("anyFile", FileMode.Open, FileAcces.Read)
use mem = new MemoryStream()
stream.CopyTo mem
let data = mem.ToArray()
```

Comment: I miss-asked my question but you gave the correct answer for my example code and question so I'l accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually ended up with the following code after realizing that a buffer is needed in lower level programming languages (I come from python). The above answer and [this](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/40048/read-text-from-stream-char-by-char) post where very helpful

```
let test fileName = 
  use stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
  use reader = new BinaryReader(stream)

  let bufferSize = 1000
  let mutable buffer :byte array = Array.zeroCreate bufferSize

  let mutable eof = false

  while reader.Read(buffer,0,bufferSize) <> 0 && not eof do
      let mutable position = 0
      while position < buffer.Length && not eof do
          let buf = buffer.[position]
          if buf <> 0uy then
              printfn "%A" buf
              printfn "%A" (Convert.ToChar(buf))
              position <- position + 1
          else
              eof <- true

test "test.txt"
```